Google reCAPTCHA v3 is always returning a score of 0.9
I have implemented Google reCAPTCHA v3 in my application. After publishing, I tested it with bots using developer tools, but it consistently returns a score of 0.9.
 var values = new Dictionary<string,
            string> {
                {
                    "secret",
                    secret
                },
                {
                    "response",
                    response
                }
            };
        var content = new System.Net.Http.FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
        var Response = hc.PostAsync("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify", content).Result;
        var responseString = Response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

I tried with bots from developer tools , always getting score of 0.9

What is the question here?

While I agree there's no explicit question, there is a fairly clear implicit question; i.e. "Why is reCAPTCHA always returning 9.0 and how can I fix it"

There are two things you can do to change the score -

recaptcha-policy -

You can create recaptcha-policy. https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-armor-recaptcha-bot-management#7.

Create a score based key -
Creating a score-based site key that always returns a set score
e.g -
gcloud recaptcha keys create --testing-score=0.2 --web --domains="domain1.com,domain2.com" --display-name="TestingKey" --integration-type=score


How does this answer the issue?

@DarkBee : with both the approach you can set the score you need. For bot testing after v2 user agents wont work.

If you have a question of your own then please post one and don't use the answer feature for this

I mistakenly wrote testing of bot which I corrected in answer. I was suggesting the ways to  change the score by using test keys. Please suggest if you have other options.

Suggest what? There is not even a question in the OP, so unsure how anyone could formulate an answer

Let OP decide if the answer suits. Otherwise free to mark it as not useful.

@Ashish.Wadekar the user isn't asking how to set a value. They're asking how to make reCAPTCHA work properly and not always return 0.9
